# Déchet / Déchets et Ordure / Ordures

Tags: vocabulaire

J'essaye de trouver quand on utilise le singulier et le pluriel pour *déchet* et *ordure*. Qui pourrait me l'expliquer ?

P.S. Ma langue maternelle est l'allemand où l'on utilise "Abfall" et "Abfälle". En fait c'est la même chose mais il y a une petite différence. Est-ce le cas aussi en français ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Le déchet est ce que l'on retire d'une matière première ou d'un produit de consommation alimentaire à l'état non préparé et qui ne convient pas à l'utilisation. Tant que l'on considère cette partie rejetée comme sous produit de la fabrication ou préparation on l'appelle déchet et souvent ce déchet est recyclable. Si l'on s'en sert dans un processus de recyclage, comme les os du bétail de boucherie que l'on ne jette pas mais qui servent à fabriquer de la nourriture pour le bétail, on peut donner à ce déchet un nom particulier mais jamais l'appeler de l'ordure. Si l'on n'a aucune utilité pour cette partie rejetée et qu'on doive soit l'enterrer soit l'incinérer, alors on peut l'appeler « ordure ». Une fois que du déchet est dans la poubelle de la maison, par exemple, on l'appelle de l'ordure.

L'ordure est quelque chose de plus général et que l'on détruit toujours ; c'est ce qui consiste en plus des déchets, de tout le petit matériel et des parties de petit mobilier cassées, ainsi que les vieux vêtements, vieux livres qui ont trainé dans la boue, emballages de toutes sortes sans plus d'utilité, verre cassé, … en d'autre mot tout ce que l'on peut trouver dans les poubelles dans les rues.

Les deux noms sont utilisable en tant que nom indénombrables. c'est à dire que l'on ne se sert pas d'articles indéfinis quand on les utilise (**un, des, quelques**) mais d'un mot ou d'une combinaison de mots appelé un partitif (**du, de la, de l'**).
Ils sont aussi utilisables en tant que noms dénombrables, c'est à dire avec les articles indéfinis et définis (**le, la, les, un, une, des**)

- Lorsque l'on prépare de la nourriture on crée beaucoup de déchet(**s**). (indénombrable ou dénombrable)
- Dès que l'on a mis ce déchet dans la poubelle on l'appelle **de l'** ordure.
- (TLFi) Mille autres menus déchets [d'un porc dépecé] qui, fondus, prendront le nom de « gressillons ».
- Il y a de l'ordure/des ordures dans la cour. (non dénombrable/dénombrable)

Comment: Merci beaucoup!! C’est un grand aide

Answer (score 2):

« Déchet » et « ordure » sont deux noms normaux. L'emploi du singulier et du pluriel se fait de manière normale comme on dirait « une voiture / des voitures ».

---

Mais voici quelques exemples

> Un déchet ménager ([définition](http://d%C3%A9chet%20m%C3%A9nager)) : micro-onde, machine à laver, un yaourt
>
> Les éboueurs récupèrent les déchet**s** ménager**s**. On peut aussi dire le ramassage des ordure**s**
>
> En France, la destination de nos déchet**s** se répartit ainsi ...
>
> Réduire nos déchet**s** !

---

> C'est quoi cette ordure, c'est sale !
>
> Voici des ordure**s** ménagères classiques ...
>
> Le pot de confiture est une ordure ménagère

---

Ensuite, en français, ces mots sont des synonymes. Les deux mots s'emploient régulièrement

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour l’explication!!

Answer (score 2):

Il y a un différence notable entre l'utilisation au singulier et au pluriel du mot ordure, et dans une moindre mesure du mot déchet.

Les **déchets**, c'est le superflu, ce dont on n'a pas besoin, ce qui *déchoit*, c'est à dire ce qui tombe  (choir, ***cadere***). C'est une chute qui n'a pas la valeur de ce qui n'est pas tombé.

Les **ordures**, ce sont des déchets qui ont pour caractéristique d'être sales, repoussants, inspirant (étymologiquement) l'horreur (ordure vient du latin ***horridus***). Ils sont souvent d'origine organique.

On pourra par exemple trouver de la nourriture en décomposition dans les ordures ménagères. Les excrément étaient aussi nommés *ordures* mais ce sens est perdu aujourd'hui.

Quand c'est pour désigner ce dont on se débarrasse dans une poubelle, *déchet* est souvent utilisé au pluriel et ordure l'est encore plus.

cf. TLFi :

> DÉCHET, subst. masc.
>   ...
>   **B. −** Souvent au *plur.* Ce qui tombe d'une matière que l'on travaille.
>   ...
>   − *P. ext.* Immondices :
>
> ---
>
> ORDURE, subst. fém.
>   **A. −** Le plus souvent au *plur.* Chose inutilisable, sale, dont on se débarrasse. Synon. déchet, détritus, immondice.

La phrase :

> *Il y a un déchet dans la poubelle.*

est possible, mais peu vraisemblable et :

> *Il y a une ordure dans la poubelle.*

est encore moins idiomatique.

Au singulier, **déchet** désigne plutôt une matière ou un type d'objet générique :

> 90% des Français le disent : « le papier est le déchet le plus facile à trier »
>
> Le mégot de cigarette est le déchet identifiable le plus fréquent sur les plages.

Quand il est utilisé au singulier, **ordure** a en revanche souvent un autre sens, celui figuré de personne détestable :

> Le Père Noël est une ordure.

Pour ce qui est de l'allemand, il me semble que *déchet* recouvre le sens de *der Abfall* alors que *les ordures*, ce serait plutôt *der Müll* (qui n'a pas de pluriel !).